# How can I prevent this applescript failing when run against completely empty iTunes library

Tags: applescript, itunes

Hi do I prevent this applescript failing when run against a completely empty iTunes library, it fails with

"iTunes got an error: Can’t get name of every file track of library playlist 1." number -1728 from name of every file track of library playlist 1

```
tell application "iTunes"
    tell every file track of library playlist 1
        script performancekludge
            property tracknames : its name
            property locs : its location
            property persistids : its persistent ID
        end script
    end tell
end tell

set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/songkong_itunes_model.txt")
set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
set eof fileref to 0

tell performancekludge
    repeat with i from 1 to length of its tracknames
        try
            set nextline to item i of its tracknames ¬
                & "::" & POSIX path of item i of its locs ¬
                & "::" & item i of its persistids
            write nextline & linefeed as «class utf8» to fileref
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

close access fileref
```

**Now fixed as follows**

```
tell application "iTunes"

    if (count of every file track of library playlist 1) is equal to 0 then
        set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/songkong_itunes_model.txt")
        set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
        set eof fileref to 0
        return
    end if

    tell every file track of library playlist 1
        script performancekludge
            property tracknames : its name
            property locs : its location
            property persistids : its persistent ID
        end script
    end tell
end tell

set thePath to (POSIX file "/tmp/songkong_itunes_model.txt")
set fileref to open for access (thePath) with write permission
set eof fileref to 0

tell performancekludge
    repeat with i from 1 to length of its tracknames
        try
            set nextline to item i of its tracknames ¬
                & "::" & POSIX path of item i of its locs ¬
                & "::" & item i of its persistids
            write nextline & linefeed as «class utf8» to fileref
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

close access fileref
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the library is empty or not...

```
tell application "iTunes"

    if (count of every file track of library playlist 1) is equal to 0 then
        return
    end if

    tell every file track of library playlist 1

    ...
```

Comment: Thx, thats worked I just add to add in resetting of file as well (shown solution in original question)